# How to change directory path from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, replace

Hello i have table pm_videos and column inside it url_flv

i want to change the directory where the videos are located from /uploads/videos to /upload/vid

how do i update mysql with the new directory location to affect all entries in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE pm_videos SET url_flv = REPLACE(url_flv,'/uploads/videos' ,'/uploads/vid') WHERE url_flv LIKE '%/uploads/videos%'
```

Answer (score 0):

use `select replace(url, '/uploads/videos','/uploads/vid') from vid` to get a replaced version of the strings. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85d027/6 .

But I would recommend to only store file names in the database and to store the unchangigng portion of the file path in your code somewhere. This saves database space.